# Bootstrap and responsive issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some issues with the responsive on bootstrap.

The desktop view is perfect, and it is the look I want it to be

[image]

But more I reduce the window, more the style is breaking

[image]

At the end on smartphone view, it's perfect. I really don't know what to do :/

[image]

Here the code : http://jsbin.com/egudor/6/edit

Comment: I can't recreate the issue. When I resize the output area, the header never moves below the paragraph and works how I assume you want it to.

Comment: I cannot recreate this either. Which browser are you experiencing the issues in?

Comment: Ok here is the whole code : http://jsbin.com/egudor/6/edit

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the `float: left` attribute you put on `.thumbnail h3` (line 33 of edit.css) and the `margin-top: 40px` of `.thumbnail p`

Works for me : http://jsbin.com/egudor/11/edit